# Any reference for the following Hadamard property

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, random-matrices, hadamard-product

Let $x \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$ be a vector of random variables with $x \sim \mathcal{N}_C (0, \Sigma_{xx})$ and let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N} $ be a Hermitian matrix (i.e. $A = A^H$ with $(\cdot)^H$ being the conjugate transpose). Through simple element-wise multiplication it can be observed that:

$$ \text{diag}(x)~ A ~\text{diag}(x)^H = A \circ (xx^H)$$
where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product. $\text{diag}(x)$ is the diagonal matrix with $x_i$ as its $i$-th diagonal element.

More specifically I am interested to show that

$$ E[ ~\text{diag}(x)~ A ~\text{diag}(x)^H ~] = A \circ \Sigma_{xx} $$
where $E[\cdot]$ is the expectation operator.

Is there any reference I can cite one of the above properties?

Comment: Isn't the expectation of $xx^H$ equal to $\Sigma_{xx}$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $\Sigma_{xx} = E[ x x^H ] $

Comment: And isn't the expectation of a matrix equal to the matrix of expectations of it's entries? If so, isn't it immediate that the expectation of $A\circ (xx^H)$ is equal to $A\circ \Sigma_{xx}$? And if so, are you only interested in a reference?

Comment: You are correct. But, I am interested to find a reference that confirms the equal sign on any of the expressions (i.e. any reference that confirms $\text{diag}(x)~ A ~\text{diag}(x)^H = A \circ (xx^H)$. Or is it so obvious that does not need any citation?

Comment: Yes, it is entirely obvious.